# Haskell code won't compile with certain variable names

Tags: haskell, haskell-linear

I'm getting an error from GHCi that I can't explain. I'm working with the following code (the vast majority of which is seemingly-irrelevant to the issue, but I can't replicate the issue with less code; commented-out lines are ones that I would like to add to replace the dummy `in 0` lines)

```
import Linear
apply x f = f x
pos xs = -- smallest i where xs!!i > 0, else length xs
    let aux xs n = case xs of
                   x:t -> if x > 0 then n
                          else aux t (n+1)
                   [] -> n
    in aux xs 0
optimize d opt d_opt funs d_funs x0 p0 eps =
    let n = length funs in
    let aux x p f_best = let feas = map (apply x) funs in
                         let i = pos feas in
                         let (g,a,f_best) =
                                 if i == n then
                                    let g = d_opt x in
                                    let g' = p !* g in
                                    let prod = g `dot` g' in
                                    let g = g / (sqrt prod) in
                                    let f_best = min (opt x) f_best in
                                    let a = (opt x - f_best) / (sqrt prod) in
                                    (g,a,f_best)
                                 else
                                    let g = (d_funs!!i) x in
                                    let g' = p !* g in
                                    let prod = g `dot` g' in
                                    let g = g / (sqrt prod) in
                                    let a = ((funs!!i) x) / (sqrt prod) in
                                    (g,a,f_best)
                         in
                         let b = (1+d*a)/(d+1) in
                         let b' = 2/(1+a) in
                         let b'' = (1-a^2)*(d^2)/(d^2-1) in
                         let h = p !* g in
                         let y = x - b*g in
                         -- let q = (p - g'*(transpose g')*b*b')*b'' in
                         -- aux y q f_best
                         0
    -- in aux x0 p0 (1/0)
    in 0
```

This code causes GHCi to throw six errors, including highlighting the `p` in `let h = p !* g in`; however, when I change that line to `let g = p !* g in` it goes through. Unfortunately, doing this and then uncommenting the next line (`let x = x - b*g in`) causes the same errors to be thrown (including highlighting the `p` in the same spot).

`p` and `p0` are supposed to be (n-by-n) square matrices using the Linear package, while `g`, `x` and `x0` are supposed to be (n-by-1) vectors; `d` is an integer, `opt` is a linear function on n-space, `funs` is a list of convex functions on n-space, `d_opt` and `d_funs` are the respective gradients, `eps` is real.

Any help with getting this to compile would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: here is one of the error messages. There are similar ones for `let g = d_opt x`, `let f_best = min (opt x) f_best`, `let g = (d_funs!!i) x`, `let a = ((funs!!i) x) / (sqrt prod)`, and `let b = (1+d*a)/(d+1)`.

```
Lenstra.hs:57:34: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 ~ m a1
      Expected type: m (m a1)
        Actual type: m (m (m a1))
    • In the first argument of ‘(!*)’, namely ‘p’
      In the expression: p !* g
      In an equation for ‘h’: h = p !* g
    • Relevant bindings include
        h :: m a1 (bound at Lenstra.hs:57:30)
        b'' :: m a1 (bound at Lenstra.hs:56:30)
        b' :: m a1 (bound at Lenstra.hs:55:30)
        b :: m a1 (bound at Lenstra.hs:54:30)
        g :: m a1 (bound at Lenstra.hs:37:31)
        a :: m a1 (bound at Lenstra.hs:37:33)
        aux :: m a1 -> m (m (m a1)) -> p8 -> p9 (bound at Lenstra.hs:35:9)
        (Some bindings suppressed; use -fmax-relevant-binds=N or -fno-max-relevant-binds)
   |
57 |                          let h = p !* g in
   |                                  ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Well that probably means the type of `p` and `q` are different.

Comment: Without even reading the question: `let x = x - b*g` defines `x` in terms of itself, not in terms of some previously-available `x` as you probably intended. Pick a new name for the new `x` and modify your code accordingly. Same for `p`. 95% confidence your problems will disappear.

Comment: But this algorithm is, imho too chaotic to effectively debug. Normally you split the logic into small parts that perform specific tasks. The amount of `let ... in ...` chaining is gigantic. While  it is not unusual to have 2-3 `let` statements, the above does not look very Haskellish. In fact it also looks very procedural.

Comment: @DanielWagner Unfortunately, I tried changing the names to `let h = p !* g` and `let y = x - b*h` (keeping the redefinition of `p` commented out) and seem to have the same compilation problem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I wish I had less chaining, but having everything substituted in was making debugging even more difficult. Is it better to e.g. stick each branch of the `if`/`else` into its own function outside of `optimize`?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin i have edited in one of the error messages to the bottom of the post. I could add the others if it would be additionally useful.

Comment: Try adding type annotations to the bindings.  That will narrow down where the infinite type is being inferred.

Comment: How did you come up with this algorithm? Are there distinct ideas in it that you could factor out into independently meaningful functions?

Comment: @dfeuer I am implementing the constrained ellipsoid method, https://stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/ellipsoid_method_notes.pdf. Unfortunately I haven't identified a good way to factor the code other than the branches of the `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several errors:

- Where the integer `d` is used as a float, you need to use `fromIntegral`, so for example:   `b = (1 + fromIntegral d * a)/(fromIntegral d + 1)`
- Scalar multiplication/division of vectors and matrices can't use `*` and `/`.  You must use the `*^`, `^*`, and `^/` operators for vectors and `!!*` and `!!/` for matrices.
- Pointwise sums and differences of vectors and matrices can't use `+` and `-`.  You must use `^+^` and `^-^` for vectors and `!+!` and `!-!` for matrices.
- For a vector `g'`, `transpose g'` isn't going to work, so `g' * transpose g'` doesn't have a prayer.  Use `outer g' g'` to get the matrix resulting from the product of `g'` as a column vector with `g'` as a row vector, if that's what you're trying to do.
- There was no `g'` in scope where `q` is defined.  Maybe you wanted to return `g'` from your `if` statement?
- `let g = some expression with g` is not going to work, as you'll create a recursive definition that loops forever.  You'll need to use a fresh variable -- you've done this correctly in some places but not in others.

There's also a significant logic error, at least in the version with your commented statements uncommented.  The function `aux` never returns anything other than a tail call to `aux`, so it will necessarily loop forever.  I don't even know what type it's supposed to return.  You need some stopping condition (probably returning `f_best` or something).

You will find it helpful to add type signatures to `optimize` and its `aux` function to keep these errors under control.  The following type-checks but still contains several bugs (infinite loops, etc.):

```
import Linear
import Data.Vector (Vector)

apply x f = f x

pos :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> Int
pos xs = -- smallest i where xs!!i > 0, else length xs
    let aux xs n = case xs of
                   x:t -> if x > 0 then n
                          else aux t (n+1)
                   [] -> n
    in aux xs 0

type Matrix a = Vector (Vector a)

optimize
  :: Integer
  -> (Vector Double -> Double)
  -> (Vector Double -> Vector Double)
  -> [Vector Double -> Double]
  -> [Vector Double -> Vector Double]
  -> Vector Double
  -> Matrix Double
  -> Double
  -> a
optimize d opt d_opt funs d_funs x0 p0 eps =
    let n = length funs in
    let aux
          :: Vector Double
          -> Matrix Double
          -> Double
          -> a
        aux x p f_best = let feas = map (apply x) funs in
                         let i = pos feas in
                         let g :: Vector Double
                             (g,g',a,f_best) =
                                 if i == n then
                                    let g = d_opt x in
                                    let g' = p !* g in
                                    let prod = g `dot` g' in
                                    let g = g ^/ (sqrt prod) in  -- **LOOP**
                                    let f_best = min (opt x) f_best in
                                    let a = (opt x - f_best) / (sqrt prod) in
                                    (g,g',a,f_best)
                                 else
                                    let g = (d_funs!!i) x in
                                    let g' = p !* g in
                                    let prod = g `dot` g' in
                                    let g = g ^/ (sqrt prod) in  -- **LOOP**
                                    let a = ((funs!!i) x) / (sqrt prod) in
                                    (g,g',a,f_best)
                         in
                         let b = (1+fromIntegral d*a)/(fromIntegral d+1) in
                         let b' = 2/(1+a) in
                         let b'' = (1-a^2)*(fromIntegral d^2)/(fromIntegral d^2-1) in
                         let h = p !* g in
                         let y = x ^-^ b*^g in
                         let q = (p !-! outer g' g' !!* (b*b')) !!* b'' in
                         aux y q f_best
    in aux x0 p0 (1/0)
```

Finally, when you get this running, you might want to submit it to the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), along with an explanation of the algorithm and some running examples.  There are lots of stylistic improvements that I think could make it make it more idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at the code so thoroughly. Yes, `outer` was exactly what I was trying to do. The definition of `q` should have referenced `g`, not `g'`; this was an artifact from a previous debug attempt. The only part of the method that I didn't get around to writing before attempting/flailing at debugging was the halt condition, which I plan to place after the definition of `i`, and which will return `x` (or go to another iteration).